# Existence of a linear transformation 2

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be finite-dimensional and let $W \subset V$ with $W \ne V$ be a proper subspace of $V$. Fix a vector $\overrightarrow v_{0}$ $\in V$ such that $\overrightarrow v_{0} \notin W$. Show that there exists a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow R$ for which $T(\overrightarrow v_{0})=1$ and $W\subset KerT$.

My approach: Let {$\overrightarrow w_{1},...,\overrightarrow w_{n}$} be a basis for $W$.

Extend it to a basis for $V$ using $\overrightarrow v_{0}$:

{$\overrightarrow w_{1},...,\overrightarrow w_{m},\overrightarrow v_{0}$} with $m\ge n$

Define $T:V\rightarrow R$ as a linear transformation such that
$T(\overrightarrow v_{0})=\overrightarrow e_{1}=1$

$T(\overrightarrow w_{1})=0$ ... $T(\overrightarrow w_{m})=0$

Claim: $W\subset KerT$

Let $\overrightarrow w \in W$
Then $\overrightarrow w=a_{1}\overrightarrow w_{1}+...+a_{n}w_{n}$

$T(w)=T(a_{1}\overrightarrow w_{1}+...+a_{n}w_{n})=0$ by construction

$\therefore w\in KerT, W\subset KerT$

Is my approach correct? I want to know what are the boundaries to using the linear extension theorem, can I just assign any value to to a transformation that suits the problem?

Comment: You can. It's equivalent to define the matrix of the transformation: the $i$-th column of this matrix is the image of the $i$-th vector of the basis of $V$. However, you may need more than one vector to extend the basis (it's not said $W$ is an [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane), it may be "smaller" than that), but that will not change your proof much.

Comment: So is my proof kind of correct? I don't get what you mean by "more than one vector" I used $1+m-n$ vectors to extend the basis with $m \ge n$ that should be it no? Thanks for the input.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: @Sadem If you found the answer to your question, please consider self-answering your question, so that it gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't pay attention to your $n$ and $m$ in the proof: the dimension of $W$ is $n$, and you add enough vectors to get a base of $V$, which is then of dimension $m+1$. The notation is a bit awkward, because $w_{n+1},\dots,w_{m}$ are not in $W$, but the proof is nevertheless correct. Also, while there is no problem with it, bear in mind that $T(w_{n+1}),\dots,T(w_{m})$ are arbitrary, and not necessarily $0$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I see, you're right, should specify that. Thank you again.